# Resetting a form via settings variable

Tags: python, django, django-settings

In my form, I got a class named `Cform` which is subclassed to [ConstanceForm](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance/blob/master/constance/admin.py#L78) `Cform(ConstanceForm)`

In my views.py

```
class ResetCView(FormView):
    template_name = 'c.htm.jinja'
    form_class = Cform
    model = CModel

    def form_valid(self.form):
        form.cleaned['C_CODE'] = settings.C_CODE
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cview))
```

In my template:

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('c-reset')}}" name="form">
          <button>Reset</button>
</form>
<form method="post" action="{{url('c-view')}}" name="form">
          {{ form.as_p}}
</form>
```

My problem is it is not updating. Form is always invalid. I just want to reset my form or its database value to a specific data.

Comment: Can you post the form.errors. if its not valid then we should have this.

Comment: Form valid is called after validation has been successful

Comment: @Sayse, yes Sir, But is there a way to just directly save it. Since my data is from a default value.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way for you to handle this is to add a clean method in the form for that field and set it there

```
def clean_c_code(self):
    self.cleaned_data['C_CODE'] = settings.C_CODE
    return self.cleaned_data['C_CODE']
```

Although,

1. Do you really need it in the form at all if its always going to have the same value (just access the setting)
2. It might not be a good idea at all, settings should stay the same as when you first run the server